# Can't upload image to a external API using axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've been trying to upload an image with axios to an external (laravel) api and it's been giving me nightmares.

resumed template:

```
<v-form>
    <v-file-input 
      label="Logo*" 
      v-model="image"
      accept="image/*"
      @change="onFileSelected"
      required
    ></v-file-input>
    <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="createProvider">Create Provider</v-btn>
</v-form>
```

Methods

```
methods: {
    onFileSelected (event) {
        this.selectedImage = event;
    },
    createProvider() {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("image", this.selectedImage, this.selectedImage.name);
    
        const config = {
            headers: {
                Authorization: this.token,
               'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        };
    
        let imageData = {
            'image': formData,
            'name': 'Provider Image', // Required Field
        }
    
        axios.post('http://fake_external_url.com/api/images', imageData, config) // laravel API
            .then(console.log)
            .catch(console.log)
    },
}
```

The error that I get in return is:

> Error: Request failed with status code 422

Request Response:

> [HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity 1374ms]

```
 {"image":{},"name":"Image Provider"}
```

I see that the image is not receiving anything.

If I console.log this.selectedImage I get:

```
File { 
    name: "happy.jpg",
    lastModified: 1596711013544,
    webkitRelativePath: "",
    size: 41292,
    type: "image/jpeg" 
}
```

If I console.log FormData I get crap

```
FormData
    ​<prototype>: FormDataPrototype
    ​​append: function append()
    ​​constructor: function ()
    ​​delete: function delete()
    ​​entries: function entries()
    ​​forEach: function forEach()
    ​​get: function get()
    ​​getAll: function getAll()
    ​​has: function has()
    ​​keys: function keys()
    ​​set: function set()
    ​​values: function values()
    ​​Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "FormData"
    ​​Symbol(Symbol.iterator): function entries()
    ​​<prototype>: Object { … }
```

My environment: localhost on a XAMPP server (php artisan serve as well). Laravel, VueJS, Vuetify latest versions.

I think my problem likes in my FormData, but it may be from the variables that it's receiving from the event click. I am out of ideas.

[EDIT] Note: I am able to upload image when using POSTMAN.
The reason why I am using event, and not the classic event.target.files[0] it's because there is no target in the response from the console.log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems.

## FormData

You need to send a FormData object, only a FormData object, and nothing but a FormData object.

If you want to pass additional data, then append it to the FormData object.

Wrapping the FormData object in another object and passing it to (for example) a JSON serializer will just break it.

## Content-Type

The `multipart/form-data` MIME type has a **mandatory** `boundary` parameter.

You have omitted it, but you can't know what it is anyway.

Do not set the `Content-Type` header manually. The underlying XHR object will read it from the FormData object.